# Is there any way to add new content to OneNote remotely?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I want to add new content to existing pages or add new pages to my OneNote notebook remotely. By email or by calling some MS OneNote API through Internet. Now I stuck with manual copying information to OneNote app.

Comment: If you set it up in Skydrive (onedrive?) then it will be accessible through any internet connection..

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear what you want here but I'll try to cover the bases.

You don't really remotely access a OneNote notebook as such, what happens is that the OneNote applications creates a copy of the notebook in the background and then keeps it in sync.

So you could use either Skydrive (live.com) or SharePoint (maybe Office 365) to host the notebook. This is what Microsoft wants you to do. It works very well and mobile (phone/tablet) access is available from just about any platform (including iOS and Android) though you are generally limited to text and pictures (not drawing which ON also supports).

Or you could use any other remotely accessible or remotely synchronised file storage such as Dropbox since a OneNote notebook is just a collection of files and folders. OneNote for Windows is perfectly happy with this but you will not get mobile access unless you use a 3rd party tool that supports that kind of connection.

Finally, you *could* create your own remote API! I wouldn't recommend it but it is possible since, as I say, OneNote notebooks are really just a collection of folders and compressed XML files and the schema *is* published so it is possible to work it out.

UPDATE: Thanks for the clarification in the comment. You *can* remotely add to OneNote **ONLY** when used with OneDrive (what used to be called live.com, onenote.com, etc). Microsoft have recently published an API for this and the link you gave in the comment below to IFTTT also has the ability to work with [OneNote on OneDrive](https://ifttt.com/recipes?channel=onenote). There are now quite a number of apps that will work with OneNote on OneDrive.

Comment: I know about this. But I wanted something like [link](https://ifttt.com/evernote).

Comment: Unfortunately, that hasn't been done by anyone. I can see that it is possible, but difficult. You would have to programme it yourself or get someone to do it for you. The weakness of ON is its focus on the client only. You would need to research the XML schema and create something to write to a file/folder structure.